# Remove melt data based on condition

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to remove any rows where the `value` of `a` >= `b`, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(day = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), var = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b"), value = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1)
```

Output:

```
  day var value
1   1   a     1
2   1   b     2
3   2   a     3
4   2   b     3
5   3   a     2
6   3   b     1
```

Desired output:

```
  day var value
1   1   a     1
2   1   b     2
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to switch from long to wide? via dcast or tidyr?

Comment: @Shape Primarily because of efficiency in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's a data.table solution for avoiding going from long to wide:

```
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[,if(value[var == 'a'] >= value[var == 'b']) .SD,by = day]
```

EDIT: I realize now that your desired output does not fit your initial inequality, so adjust inequality to match :)

EDIT2: if you don't want to do it in data.table, then here's the dplyr solution

```
df %>% group_by(day) %>% filter(value[var == 'a'] >= value[var == 'b'])
```

EDIT3: if you want to put NA's in then this

```
df %>% group_by(day) %>% mutate(value = if(value[var == 'a'] >= value[var == 'b']) as.numeric(NA) else value)
```

EDIT4: NOTE this last solution appears to expose a bug, where NA's are handled strangely, see here:[Why is dplyr removing values not met by condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34485798/why-is-dplyr-removing-values-not-met-by-condition#comment56713996_34485798)

Comment: Thanks, but I would prefer to not use `data.table` because of the nature of the script I'm working with.  I'd have to convert all my other `data.frames` into `data.tables`, which is an added step that will slow down my code

Comment: Thanks!  This will work.  What if instead of removing I just want to place `NA` in the rows?

Comment: Put the NA's where? so you just want a new column that has TRUE or NA? (wouldn't TRUE/FALSE be easier?)

Comment: Just replace the `value` with `NA` if the condition is met.

Comment: edited, if the solution fits, can you accept the answer?

Answer (score 3):

Shape's answer is a correct approach to address your problem.
Just to extends Shape's answer I want to contribute with a little more generic solution.
An [eav](https://github.com/jangorecki/dwtools/blob/7ea13a014381463c5266ee71ec5421378c788a2d/R/eav.R) function in package [dwtools](https://github.com/jangorecki/dwtools) is designed to address [Entity-attribute-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) data structures by easier calculation on measures. Function is defined below, you don't need [dwtools](https://github.com/jangorecki/dwtools) package.
It calculates `rm` variable for each group. Formula for a calculations can be the same as quoted `j` arg to `[.data.table` call after melting your EAV, and before dcasting to EAV again.

```
library(data.table)
eav = function(x, j, id.vars = key(x)[-length(key(x))], variable.name = key(x)[length(key(x))], measure.vars = names(x)[!(names(x) %in% key(x))], fun.aggregate = sum, shift.on = character(), wide=FALSE){
    stopifnot(is.data.table(x))
    r <- x[,lapply(.SD,fun.aggregate),c(id.vars,variable.name),.SDcols=measure.vars
           ][,dcast(.SD,formula=as.formula(paste(paste(id.vars,collapse=' + '),paste(variable.name,collapse=' + '),sep=' ~ ')),fun.aggregate=fun.aggregate,value.var=measure.vars)
             ][,eval(j), by = eval(id.vars[!(id.vars %in% shift.on)])
               ]
    if(wide) r[] else melt(r,id.vars=id.vars, variable.name=variable.name, value.name=measure.vars)[,.SD,keyby=c(id.vars,variable.name)]
}

df = data.frame(day = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), var = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b"), value = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1))
dt = as.data.table(df)
setkey(dt, day, var)
r = eav(dt, quote(rm := as.numeric(a >= b)))
print(r)
#   day var value
#1:   1   a     1
#2:   1   b     2
#3:   1  rm     0
#4:   2   a     3
#5:   2   b     3
#6:   2  rm     1
#7:   3   a     2
#8:   3   b     1
#9:   3  rm     1
r[, if(value[var=="rm"] == 0) .SD, by = day
  ][var!="rm"] # you need to exclude temporary variable
#   day var value
#1:   1   a     1
#2:   1   b     2
```

This solution may also be slower than Shape's (you can populate your sample of big data so it can be measured), but may be easier for complex computations on many measures in EAV, and supports shift'ing - see [eav examples](https://github.com/jangorecki/dwtools/blob/7ea13a014381463c5266ee71ec5421378c788a2d/tests/example-eav.R).