# Why is dplyr removing values not met by condition?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm using `dplyr` to replace the `value` with `NA` if a condition is met, but it's putting `NA` in place where it shouldn't be.

dput:

```
df <- structure(list(id = c("USC00231275", "USC00231275", "USC00231275", 
"USC00231275", "USC00231275", "USC00231275", "USC00231275", "USC00231275", 
"USC00231275", "USC00231275"), element = c("TMAX", "TMIN", "TMAX", 
"TMIN", "TMAX", "TMIN", "TMAX", "TMIN", "TMAX", "TMIN"), year = c(1937, 
1937, 1937, 1937, 1937, 1937, 1937, 1937, 1937, 1937), month = c(5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), day = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 
5), date = structure(c(-11933, -11933, -11932, -11932, -11931, 
-11931, -11930, -11930, -11929, -11929), class = "Date"), value = c(0, 
53.96, 68, 44.96, 62.06, 53.96, 73.04, 53.96, 69.08, 50)), .Names = c("id", 
"element", "year", "month", "day", "date", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

`data.frame` (Note: condition is only met on row 1 and 2)

```
            id element year month day       date value
1  USC00231275    TMAX 1937     5   1 1937-05-01  0.00
2  USC00231275    TMIN 1937     5   1 1937-05-01 53.96
3  USC00231275    TMAX 1937     5   2 1937-05-02 68.00
4  USC00231275    TMIN 1937     5   2 1937-05-02 44.96
5  USC00231275    TMAX 1937     5   3 1937-05-03 62.06
6  USC00231275    TMIN 1937     5   3 1937-05-03 53.96
7  USC00231275    TMAX 1937     5   4 1937-05-04 73.04
8  USC00231275    TMIN 1937     5   4 1937-05-04 53.96
9  USC00231275    TMAX 1937     5   5 1937-05-05 69.08
10 USC00231275    TMIN 1937     5   5 1937-05-05 50.00
```

`dplyr`

```
df %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  mutate(
    value = if(value[element == 'TMIN'] >= value[element == 'TMAX'])
      as.numeric(NA) else value
  )

            id element  year month   day       date value
         (chr)   (chr) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)     (date) (dbl)
1  USC00231275    TMAX  1937     5     1 1937-05-01    NA
2  USC00231275    TMIN  1937     5     1 1937-05-01    NA
3  USC00231275    TMAX  1937     5     2 1937-05-02 68.00
4  USC00231275    TMIN  1937     5     2 1937-05-02 44.96
5  USC00231275    TMAX  1937     5     3 1937-05-03    NA
6  USC00231275    TMIN  1937     5     3 1937-05-03    NA
7  USC00231275    TMAX  1937     5     4 1937-05-04 73.04
8  USC00231275    TMIN  1937     5     4 1937-05-04 53.96
9  USC00231275    TMAX  1937     5     5 1937-05-05 69.08
10 USC00231275    TMIN  1937     5     5 1937-05-05 50.00
```

Notice that the only rows that should change are `1` and `2`, but `dplyr` changed rows `5` and `6` even though the conditions were not met.

Comment: Wow, I stared at this for a bit, try this: `z <- df %>% group_by(year,month,day) %>% mutate(test = diff(value)) %>% ungroup %>% mutate(value2 = ifelse(test > 0, NA, as.numeric(value)))` This works, but if you remove the ungroup suddenly the NA's are back again... I'm somewhat mystified

Comment: @Shape Yes, this was from your previous answer and doesn't seem to work on the original dataset.  Very strange I thought.  Thanks!

Comment: it's an issue apparently with using NA as the replacement value, take a look at this: `df %>% group_by(year,month,day) %>% mutate(value = if(value[element == 'TMIN'] >= value[element == 'TMAX']) 1 else value)` this works. But the NA is causing problems, this sounds like a bug

Comment: You can hack it by using Inf instead of NA, but that's not ideal

Comment: Maybe I'll just use 9999 and replace those with NA afterwards.

Comment: I would probably use the Inf approach over 9999, it's going to be exactly like NA, unless you divide

Comment: Yeah this looks like a bug. I thought it was due to the weird use of `if` rather than the vectorized `ifelse`, but that gives the same error: `df %>% group_by(date) %>% mutate(value = ifelse((element == "TMAX" & value == max(value))| (element == "TMIN" & value == min(value)), value, NA))`

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1545) seems relevant

Comment: @jbaums Thanks!  I'll also report this to see if it is a bug.

Comment: It is definitely a bug. If you just evaluate the condition and mutate the boolean value, it shows the correct values: df %>% group_by(date) %>% mutate(condition = value[element == 'TMIN'] >= value[element == 'TMAX']).

Comment: The NA part of your example works correctly for me using the development version of *dplyr*.

Comment: I actually don't think this is a bug but it will take some time to dig into this to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should do what you are trying to do

```
df %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  mutate(new_value = ifelse( ( (value[element == 'TMIN'] >= value[element == 'TMAX']) & element=='TMIN'), NA, value)) %>%
  ungroup
```

For the question of whether this is a bug or not, I don't think it is.  Looking at just the data for the one year, where TMIN >= TMAX, you have the following

```
df %>%
  filter(date == '1937-05-01') %>%
  mutate(res = (value[element == 'TMIN'] >= value[element == 'TMAX'])) %>%
  mutate(new_value = ifelse( (res & element=='TMIN'), NA, value))

           id element year month day       date value  res new_value
1 USC00231275    TMAX 1937     5   1 1937-05-01  0.00 TRUE         0
2 USC00231275    TMIN 1937     5   1 1937-05-01 53.96 TRUE        NA
```

The construct `value[element == 'TMIN'] >= value[element == 'TMAX'])` will always be true as can be seen in the `res` column.  The code below breaks this down a bit to hopefully clarify (I hope).

```
### Just looking at one date
> df2 <- df %>% filter(date == '1937-05-01')
> df2
           id element year month day       date value
1 USC00231275    TMAX 1937     5   1 1937-05-01  0.00
2 USC00231275    TMIN 1937     5   1 1937-05-01 53.96

### This comparison will be recycled for every element in the group,
### so it will always be TRUE or always FALSE.
> c(df2$value[df2$element == 'TMIN'], df2$value[df2$element == 'TMAX'])
[1] 53.96  0.00
```

Since there is one comparison for the entire group, they will always see TRUE or always FALSE.

The code that gives the correct result shows how the comparison can be gotten around.

One possible final solution could be:

```
df %>%
   group_by(date) %>%
   mutate(value = ifelse( ( (value[element == 'TMIN'] >= value[element == 'TMAX']) & element=='TMIN'), NA, value)) %>%
   ungroup
```

Comment: So while I agree that ifelse can get around this, the single TRUE or false was the intention of the original code. It has the result of running a single operation for each group, based on 2 lookups, rather than multiple, vectorized comparisons. (This is especially true if your long data has more factors than 'a' and 'b', but you still want to include all the group data).  When a single TRUE/FALSE is returned, values are typically multiplied. This is something NA should do as well as any other value.